# How to use factory_bot to build objects that lack accessor methods?

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

Given a data model that lacks accessor methods,

```rb
class Person
  attr_reader :name # but NO attr_accessor
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :person do
    name { 'Grace' }
  end
end
```

How can I use `factory_bot` to build a `Person`? If we try `build :person` we get:

```
NoMethodError .. undefined method `name='
```

I wrote a [custom build strategy](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/main/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-strategies) which works, but I am not pleased with it because I had to use `instance_variable_get` to access private library objects.

```rb
class BuildNew
  def association(runner)
    runner.run
  end

  # @param evaluation [FactoryBot::Evaluation]
  def result(evaluation)
    attributes = evaluation.hash
    model_class = evaluation.instance_variable_get(:@attribute_assigner).send(:build_class_instance).class
    model_class.new(attributes)
  end
end
FactoryBot.register_strategy(:build_new, BuildNew)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems the custom build strategy was unnecessary. This can be done much more simply using `initialize_with`.

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :person do
    initialize_with { new(attributes) }
    name { 'Grace' }
  end
end
```